# How to edit a control within a FireMonkey style outside of the style designer?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In this scenario, I created a default button on my FireMonkey HD application via RADStudio XE2. I then created a custom style for the button, named "Style1". This style is very much similar to the default button style, however, it has a TImage control next to the TText control.

*In simple words, a button with an image next to the text.*

Now, I'll apply an image to the TImage control for the button? Because if I apply an image to the TImage control **VIA** the style designer, the other controls who use the style will also get the same image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it at runtime.
at first you have to name your TImage style object, for ex. 'btnimg'
after that you can find it by name using `FindStyleResource`:

```
procedure LoadImage(btn : TButton; imgFileName : string);
var img : TImage;
begin
    img := btn.FindStyleResource('btnimg') as TImage;

    if not assigned(img) then exit;

    img.bitmap.LoadFromFile(imgFileName); 
end;
```