# Create Image Button in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Applies to XE6, Firemonkey

I am creating a button with an image on it by customizing a TSpeedButton in firemonkey. I am doing this by adding an image to the TSpeedButton in the style editor. The new button works ok. I now want to make another image button so I thought I'd copy and paste the first button on the form. I changed the image in the copied button (via the style editor) and when I hit Apply and Close the new button gets the new image. However I also notice that the original button I copied from also get the new image. So now I have two buttons with the same image. Other than creating a completely new button and adding a new image (which does allow me to have buttons with unique images), is there a way to create buttons that have their own styles using copy/paste?

I noticed this question is related to [How to edit a control within a FireMonkey style outside of the style designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346867/how-to-edit-a-control-within-a-firemonkey-style-outside-of-the-style-designer?rq=1) but here I want to do the same thing but from the IDE, not programmatically.

Comment: I think I figured it out: 1: Create button with image on it; 2) Copy and paste button; 3) In the property editor for the second button, change the name of the StyleLookup name to a new name. That appears to create a new style for the copied button. First time I tried this I got some extra styles in the style editor (with duplicate names) which I couldn't delete or select so I had to delete all the buttons and try again. Unless there is a better answer I will promote this comment to be the answer in 24 hours.

Comment: One problem I noticed with the above approach which negates the whole point of coping a button. When you change the name of the style the button loses all it previous style information, meaning the button has to be designed again. This can't be the way to do it.

Comment: Can't you simply add an image control as a child to the button? The style shouldn't contain the image then.

Comment: Using Styles to individualize multiple components of the same type is a really inefficient way of doing things since it was never designed for such a purpose.

Comment: @Rabbe: Do you mean add the child in the style editor or programmatically at runtime?

Comment: @Vonca: What is best practice in this case?

Comment: If you look my answer to the other question, my component has an option to specify an image at design time. Thus every button has the same style but uses a different image.

Comment: @Rabbe: I understand what you're getting at. Didn't realize we could move things around on the structure panel, I've been fixated too much on the style editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They exist other approach to this. This is a consumer of resources, but they works as you want.

1 - Drop a **TSpeedButton** on your Form.

2 - Drop a **TImage** control on your Form.

3 - With the **Structure View** (in opposite to the form designer), drop the Image1 component on the SpeedButton1 component, making that TSpeedButton belongs the owner of the Image1.

3 - Now adjust the dimensions of the Image1 to make it the same as the SpeedButton.

4 - On the **Structure View**, one more time, you must select Image1 and expand it. It appears a MultiResBitMap owned component.

5 - Expand too this component: **MultiResBitmap**. It appears a **TFixedBitmapItem** with the name "0 - Normal (1,000).

6 - on the **Object Inpector** click on the (...) of his property Bitmap.

Now you can copy this structure, based on a Speed button and change the Bitmap of each one!

7 - HINT!!!    You must **set HitTest of the Image as False,** and the same property of the button as True. In other case they is going to seem that the event handler of the SpeedButton don't fires.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. When I moved the timage on to the speedbutton in the structure view, the timage became a child of the speedbutton as you predicted but it didn't move on the form. The timage and speedbutton stayed visually separate.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you mean, also move the timage on the form onto the button itself. One last thing, is there any simple way to set the transparency?

Comment: It might help to set the images Align property to Client.

Comment: Figure out how to set transparency, use the property MultiresBitmap in TImage itself, this bring up a new dialog box, where you can load the image and set the transparency color. This also means one doesn't have to expand to TFixedBitmapItem. I'll make a YouTube video of this.

Comment: Video illustrating one way to make an image button.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STjQdGDmcNk&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Comment: I've just seen your video. Good job!!!  Can you make a reference to this question in stackoverflow? Please!
It may be usefull have this cross reference.

Comment: With FireMonkey it's important, never miss of mind that any component my be child of any other component. This is a good manner of getting synergies on the platform.

Comment: Sure I can add a cross-reference to stackoverflow, good idea. Thanks for your help on this!